# Extended tag field joomla article custom field

Tags: articles, tags, custom-field, article-manager

I have some joomla custom fields in articles.
But I need 3 custom fields that should behave like the joomla "tags" so that, besides selecting from the options available, the user can also insert a new one that automatically should be available after that.
But this new "tags" should store data in different places so that there would be different options for each field.
Is there any detailed tutorial explaining how to do this (I'm not a developer)? Or an extension?!
Thanks